# syncing difficulty with local .config files

Tags: linux, server-side, symlink

file **'/srv/web.config'** and **'/var/www/web.config'** should have same content and any changes made to the file **'/srv/web.config'** should get updated in **'/var/www/web.config'** automatically. How can I do it?

Comment: Search for soft linking files on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlink concept. do this with below command:

```
ln -s /example/path/source /example/path/dest
```

for your mistake you can run this command:

```
ln -s /srv/web.config /var/www/web.config
```